# Curses using changing data

Tags: python

I have the following code. The number range increments by 1 each time. i.e 1-9 then 2-10 etc.
I want to display this within a shell window using python via curses.

The goal is to have a list of text that is constantly changing.

```
from itertools import cycle
import curses, contextlib, time

@contextlib.contextmanager
def curses_screen():
    """Contextmanager's version of curses.wrapper()."""
    try:
        stdscr=curses.initscr()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        stdscr.keypad(1)
        try: curses.start_color()
        except: pass

        yield stdscr
    finally:
        stdscr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.nocbreak()
        curses.endwin()

with curses_screen() as stdscr:
    pad = curses.newpad(100, 100)
    pad.addstr(0,0, curses.longname())

    coord = 5, 5, 10, 75
    # simulate changing text #
    for z in range(1,10):
        s,e = z+1,z+10
        for x in range(s,e):
            pad.addstr(x,0, str(x))
    pad.refresh(0, 0, *coord)
```

With this code nothing is printed to the screen ?
Note : The reason Ive used a newpad is so that I eventually scroll through this list.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's not that nothing is printed to the screen, it's that you do all your printing in a few microseconds, at which point you restore the pre-`curses` screen and exit. Throw in a `pad.getch()` or just a `time.sleep(1)` and you'll see the output.

If you want this to go slowly enough that you can watch it, instead of as fast as your computer can count up numbers, you'll want a delay (and a `refresh`) inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I tried this and I still had no luck. Ive updated the question with the code Im now trying.

Comment: you only do a refresh once - and then exit - you need to do the sleep and refresh in your loop

Comment: When I run this code the refresh call generates an error :     pad.refresh(0, 0, *coord)
_curses.error: prefresh() returned ERR - I think you need to sort that error. And I still sure your refresh is in the wrong place - you need to refresh after every sleep (once your refresh works).

Comment: @felix001: You haven't actually did what Tony Suffolk suggested. Also, do not keep changing your question to match the answer; that makes it, and all of the comments and answers, useless to anyone else who has a similar problem.

Comment: @abarmet I appreciate what you are saying. However Ive tried multiple things based on the answers which have not worked. If you have an answer that you believe will resolve my original issue then just post an answer with the code. Thanks